# How can I read Data that is not changing?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read Data from a Firebase Realtime Database that is not changing. I need to know a Variable the Moment the App starts and I need to access it from diffrent devices.

```
FirebaseDatabase db = com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = db.getReference("Counter");
```

Just the usual Stuff to get a Reference.
[How my Database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFwoO.png)

```
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            value = dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
            Log.d("message", "value is: " + value);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("message", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
        });
```

This can only read values if something is changing.

Comment: I would love something like int value = myRef.getValue(); is there an option that  does that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a `ValueEventListener` with `addValueEventListener`, its `onDataChange` is called right away with the data at that location. It then gets called for any change to the data after that.

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events):

> This [`onDataChange`] method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including children, changes.